# build failed after getting java.lang.NullPointerException: The types section is required error in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

```
       jenkins version  1.573
```

i am getting following error after build saying following error

```
\WidgetEntityTest::testCrudExercises_bundletemplatewidgets
     [exec] 1..278
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ... done
     [exec] 
     [exec] Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 30 minutes 19 seconds
Terminating xvnc.
$ vncserver -kill :42
Killing Xvnc process ID 20680
FATAL: The types section is required.
java.lang.NullPointerException: The types section is required.
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.XUnitProcessor.<init>(XUnitProcessor.java:41)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.XUnitBuilder.perform(XUnitBuilder.java:76)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
```

i have ugraded to the jenkins 1.573 and i suspect it is the issue as there is no code change in changelogs.
i am totally confused weather it is the problem with the Xvnc plugin or the jenkins version itself.never came accross the null pointer issue in past with jenkins.please help i had four build failed with same error now.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31834440/2747593

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the Xvnc plugin. If it resolves the problem, you have your answer :)