# Why is the XUnit plugin not working with Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, xunit

I launched the tests IDE (selenium) from jenkins and I uploaded the XUNIT plugin for having a nice report of test but at the end I obtained this message of ERROR :

Tests failed, see result file for details:

```
D:\FTP\stm_atos_automatisation\rapports\ff39\rapport_ff39.html ERROR: Build step failed with exception java.lang.NullPointerException: The types section is required.
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.XUnitProcessor.<init>(XUnitProcessor.java:65)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.xunit.XUnitPublisher.perform(XUnitPublisher.java:111)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:381) Build step 'Publish xUnit test result report' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error too when I first enabled the XUnit plugin.

I hadn't realized (or had forgotten) that I needed to add a report type to the XUnit build step configuration. To do so, click `Add` and then select the type of report you want parsed (for me it was `PHPUnit-3.x`). See [this screenshot](http://codeception.com/images/jenkins/Jenk7.png). You'll also have to specify the path to the XML report files that you want parsed. (I'm using Codeception, so it was `tests/_log/*.xml`.)

Comment: how do you specify the path to the report files?

Comment: @Anentropic: After you select the type of report, an additional text box will appear, and that is where you specify the path.

Comment: I've specified a path to my result files, it has found three, yet it only publishes a report for the first of the files that it finds, do you know how to make it report on multiple files?